# Trying to make previous app compatible with Lollipop WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to update an Android app. It was developed with a target API of 21.  It works fine on my API 19 phone (and a few other devices with various build versions), but not on my new API 22 phone.  It's the new WebView package.  The app consists primarily of links to either html assets or to live web pages via string arrays.  The links to the assets work fine, but the links to web sites give me an error. For example:
"Webpage not available. The webpage at http://www.ushistory.org/franklin/info could not be loaded because net::ERR_CACHE_MISS"

I've looked at developer.android.com and other resources and adjusted the code to get this:

```
    WebView resWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
    WebSettings webSettings = resWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        resWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        resWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings
                .MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(resWebView, true);
    }
        resWebView.loadUrl("http://www.ushistory.org/franklin/info ");  
                scroller.addView(resWebView);
```

I've played with different modes, but it still doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I didn't need any of the changes above.  I installed system updates to both phones yesterday and went back to the original code (minus the scroller):

```
WebView resWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
WebSettings webSettings = resWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
resWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add permissions on Manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

and set cache as enabled:

```
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```